# UITableViewIndex Tableview section index doesn't fall under safearea automatically for iPhoneX

Tags: uitableview, ios11, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide, uilayoutguide

As the contentView of UITableView comes safe area,but the default UITableViewIndex(A.B..Z) at the right of table doesn't comes under safe area and getting clipped by iPhone X landscape but the native Contacts App works perfect.

Comment: Found why this is happening. This is due to the contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior of iOS 11 Scrollview UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever .

Comment: Hi, could you post your final solution? Thank you.